# How do i get the native language localisation on a smartphone from browser javascript?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, mobile-website

I'm working on a mobile website and I want to change languages by the phone native defaults.

Is there any solution to do it? I mean there are three states:

1. the phone lang setting is "eng"
2. the phone lang setting is "hun"
3. the phone lang setting is other foreign lang, then the website lang is "eng"

I want to use it on iOS and Android too.

Thx

Comment: Sorry I forget. I want to automatically change language by the phone native defaults and with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you are still interested in an answer:
you can use `navigator.appVersion`, see the following JavaScript snippet:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert(navigator.appVersion);
  </script>
```

and the corresponding result on a Android device with Android 2.2:
[image: screenshot]
you just have to parse for the language, in the example it is **de-de**.
Sorry, I do not have an iPhone, but the result is probably similar...

Comment: sorry I totally forgot follow the answer, probably meanwhile I figured out the solution, but you earned the point:)